# Mobile 2m / 70cm dual band with aviation frequency TX capability

Tags: united-states, am

Forgive what may be a basic inquiry from a new enthusiast. I am new to amateur radio, just barely passed Technician and General tests. I am also a pilot and have an RR class licence. I believe that I have what is required to transmit on aviation frequencies from the ground according to 47 CFR Part 87 Subpart B §87.18 and §87.47. (My intent is to provide periodic back-country ground support to fellow pilots.) I have found several mobile radios that can monitor aviation frequencies but haven't found one that can transmit. Is there such a thing? There appears to be a few portable models that can, but haven't been able to find a mobile transceiver.

Comment: Are you looking for a radio that can transmit on the aviation band and also amateur bands?

Comment: @rclocher3 Yes I am, a "car mounted" mobile unit if there is such a thing. Given previous response it seems to be an unlikely combination.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on your new license!

I don't believe you will find this type of radio. The aviation band uses amplitude modulation and the amateur bands for conventional repeaters and local communications use frequency modulation.

The aviation band radio must be FCC certified to part 87 to be legally used for transmitting. The FAA must also approve the radio prior to FCC certification commencing.

Add to all of this the limited market for such a combined radio and the likelihood is quite small.

If you add a requirement such as DMR or Fusion for the amateur radio portion, the likelihood is further decreased.

Comment: Thank you Glenn. Much appreciated. I was lulled into a false sense of hope with several mobile radios that can apparently RX on aviation frequencies!

Comment: @Rod You are welcome - I wish I had better news though. Please stay active on SE!

Answer (score -1):

I did a quick Google search, and found this one : http://www.icomamerica.com/en/products/avionics/mobile/a120/default.aspx

Also there is this one : http://www.icomamerica.com/en/products/avionics/panelmount/a220/default.aspx

I am sure others exist, but I found those with a quick search. I can't comment as to their suitability, however.

This one claims to cover all the frequencies you wanted : http://www.icomamerica.com/en/products/avionics/mobile/xbandair/default.aspx

Comment: These do not appear to have 2m / 70cm capability, and the X Band Air is a rack mount. Was hoping for an "all in one" solution for the car. Thanks for the reply!